# I'm unable to debug an Azure Function - Azure.Mesaging.ServiceBus: The connection string could not be parsed

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, endpoint

Here's the error:

"The listener for function '<my_function>' was unable to start. Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus: The connection string could not be parsed; either it was malformed or contains no well-known tokens."

Someone else configured this, and there is no Shared Access service policy.  No event hub.  It's using topics, and AD manages identities.  No connection string is necessary.

Any ideas what the magic setting name is ?  I read the manual, and it was pretty useless.

It was working a couple of weeks ago with the same codebase.  Is there a way to see the history of the configuration changes in Azure, maybe?

Comment: You can check the [activity log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log) for the function, or even up to the resource group level, to see any recent changes.

Comment: I did, and it's not showing anything helpful.  The dead letter queue is populated with a few messages that couldn't be consumed.  The server logs show an OOM condition, and I rebooted.  No joy.

Comment: It may be problem with your connection string, make sure to check *(;)* this is not present at the end of connection string. Use the same connection string which is from your Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work again.

The problem was that Azure automatically removed subscriptions on the server-side by default after 2 weeks of inactivity.

With the subscriptions missing, it was looking for a connection string.

By the way, if you move a component from active to disabled in subscriptions, you might cause several thousand exceptions per millisecond, resulting in several thousand dollars of monthly data ingestion costs.

Thanks to everyone who gave me ideas, it helped.